# Google one tap sign in on Android with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin, mobile-development, googlesigninaccount

I'm a beginner in Flutter and need an assistance to integrate Google one tap sign in into my code with [google_one_tap_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_one_tap_sign_in) Flutter package.

Here's the code:

```
@override
  Future<TheUser?> signInWithCredential() async {
    final String _webClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    var googleAccount = await GoogleOneTapSignIn.startSignIn(webClientId: _webClientId);
    // final googleAccount = await GoogleAuth.instance.getSignedInAccount();
    if (googleAccount != null) {
      final googleAuth = await googleAccount.authentication;
      if (googleAuth.accessToken != null || googleAuth.idToken != null) {
        final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken),
        );

        return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
      } else {
        throw PlatformException(
          code: 'ERROR_MISSING_GOOGLE_AUTH_TOKEN',
          message: 'Error Missing Google Auth Token',
        );
      }
    } else {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
        message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
      );
    }
  }
```

I don't know how to write the rest of the code inside "if (googleAccount != null) {}".